# Почему функция unlink() не видит файл?

Tags: php

Хочу удалить файл из папки так как папок и файлов много я подставляю их имена через переменную `unlink('files/$loc/cards/$name.php');`, но функция unlink не видит их, хотя если вставить так `unlink('files/moduli/cards/card.php');` все работает, скажите в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Двойные кавычки нужны

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из мануала https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php:

> **Замечание**: В отличие от синтаксиса двойных кавычек и heredoc, переменные и управляющие последовательности для специальных символов, заключенных в одинарные кавычки, не обрабатываются.

и

> Cамым важным свойством строк в **двойных кавычках является обработка переменных**.

Итог:

```
// Выводит: Переменные $expand и $either не разворачиваются
echo 'Переменные $expand и $either не разворачиваются';
```

а вот так нужно:

```
echo "Значения в переменных $expand $either отобразятся!!!";
```

Answer (score 2):

Что бы переменные были видны в кавычках нужно использовать двойные кавычки.

`unlink("files/$loc/cards/$name.php");`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно это все написать в двойных кавычках

unlink("files/$loc/cards/$name.php");

Но если хочешь в одинарных кавычках.  То можно и так

unlink('files/'.$loc.'/cards/'.$name.'.php');